# Thread-safety of `std::function::operator()`

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it safe to call a `std::function<void(int)>&` from several threads, provided the underlying lambda is thread-safe?

For instance ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/jhf3hscr8)):

```cpp
void target(int i, std::deque<std::function<void(int)>>* queue) {
  std::function<void(int)>& f = queue->front();
  f(i);
}

int main() {
  std::mutex mu;
  int count = 0;
  std::function<void(int)> f = [&](int i) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
    count += i;
  };

  std::deque<std::function<void(int)>> queue;
  queue.push_back(std::move(f));

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back(target, i, &queue);
  }

  for (std::thread& thread : threads) {
     thread.join();
  }
  std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [This `std::function` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) doesn't mention it, so I would assume it's *not* thread-safe. But that only goes for code that can set and call the function simultaneously. If there are no parallel threads setting and fetching the function, then the actual call itself would be just as thread-safe as any other call, which is really irrelevant. That's for the actual *call* of the function. The code inside the function might not be thread-safe, but it doesn't affect the call itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is unclear what you try to say. Calling multiple `const` operations on the same object from multiple threads is thread-safe. It is when some of the operations aren't `const` the problems occur. So the code here is perfectly fine.

Comment: To answer the *generic* question: "Is it safe to call a `std::function<void(int)>&` from several threads, provided the underlying lambda is thread-safe?" the answer is no. The `std::function` object and its functions itself have no built-in thread safety. For the very specific example you show? It should be thread-safe and fine.

Answer (score 4):

The operator `()` of `std::function` is marked as `const`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator() therefore calling it from multiple threads is thread-safe as it causes no changes to the `std::function`. The lambda function that the `std::function` wraps modifies an external variable guarded by a mutex so it is thread-safe too.

Thus the operations are thread-safe.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I suspect it's not that simple. Obviously `operator()` has some kind of side effect in general (e.g., might change captured variables). Googling finds [papers like this one](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4348.html) that discuss the implications of that.

Comment: That's not really what `const` qualified functions mean. It just means that this specific function should not modify the object (though it still can with a `const_cast`) and can therefore be called on `const` qualified objects. It doesn't protect against other threads modifying the `std::function` object at the same time, leading to a data-race. And the function stored in the object, there are no guarantees about that at all. For the very specific code in the question, it might be possible to answer yes or no, but for the generic case there are no guarantees about thread safety.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude he asked about this calling example. If there was a non-`const` call to the `std::function` or some other modification inside the lambda it would be something else.

Comment: @heiner the side-effects is modifying objects outside of `std::function` which are guarded here by the mutex.

Comment: @heiner the paper talks about `std::function` wrapping objects whose operator () is non-const. There's a bit of design issue that `std::function` accepts such classes. That's being said, the lambda's operator () are implicitly const and it can only modify object external to the lambda.